# External Login using Custom API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I have 2 projects one **Web API** that have a simple [/Token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens) api that returns a token for the logged in user

and the second project is **.NET Core** that will use the URL/Token method in the login form.

Here is the code on the method that is used to login in the second project

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {

        var requestBody = new { grant_type = "password", username = Input.Email, password = Input.Password };
        var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:49470/Token"))
        { 
            req.Content = new StringContent("{\"grant_type\":\"password\",\"username\":" + Input.Email + ",\"password\":" + Input.Password + "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var rep = await client.SendAsync(req))
            {
                rep.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var content = await rep.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error i'm facing:
[image: Error i'm facing]
The problem that i'm facing i always get a **400 (Bad Request**) Error, ps: i'm new in **.netcore**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, the problem was the [api\Token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens) body didn't accept the structure of the json parsed string

Simply i've used

```
var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49470/Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + Input.Email + "&password=" + Input.Password, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```